# extract data between 4th & 5th

Tags: sql, string, split

Good afternoon

I am working on some data and using basic sql to pull the full field information through but I would like to refine this to specific piece of information between 2 characters (:) and I am fairly new to SQL.

I am using the code below to pull the full field through

```
SUBSTRING(var_value,15,4)END AS OutputFull
```

But I need only pull the information from the field output between the 4th & 5th":" to show "thisisatest" instead of "do::this from the info::thisisatest::K::99"

What would be the best way to do this?

thanks in advance
Gavin

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: Not sure I am using HUE to pull the data

Comment: you really need to show us the data in the table for us to have any idea what you are talking about

Comment: You probably want to use a regex expression to solve this but we can't know without 1) knowing what platform you are using and 2) seeing examples of your data.

Comment: HUE is the Query application -- what DB are you connecting to.

Comment: Hue connects to any database (see: [connectors](https://docs.gethue.com/administrator/configuration/connectors/) )  Which one is configured at your site?

Comment: If your delimiter is always `::` it might be easier to extract the data between the 1st and 2nd `::` instead of the 4th and 5th `:`

Comment: thank you @WOUNDEDStevenJones I ended up using the split_part(field,'::',3) to pull the info in the end.

Answer (score 1):

When you use MySQL, you can do it using [SUBSTIRNG_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select substring_index(substring_index("do::this from the info::thisisatest::K::99",":",5),":",-1);
```

The substring_index(...,":",5) will get the first part of the string ("do::this from the info::thisisatest"), then the substring(...,":",-1) will that the last part of that string.

For other databases, other functions exist.